# Storing a method in a scriptable object UNITY 5

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, methods

I created a scriptable object, what i want is being able to store a method in my scriptable object so I can make every object do something diferent when it's method is called, I have searched in internet but I can't find any solution for this

There's another way to do this?, to make scriptable objects that can do something diferent using diferents parts of code?

I'm using c#

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're trying to do. You don't "store" methods. There are *delegates* which are *method references* which can be used as a variable, but that doesn't match your intended useage.

Comment: Possibly what you're looking for is to make an `abstract` scriptable object which you can then subclass with actual functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a int on the function, your function(int n)
When you call it just change the N depending of the gameobject.
Also you can use herency but its more difficult